# How do I create a generic function that calls MatDialog on an abstract utilitary class?

Tags: angular

I have an utilitary class that I use to store functions used throughout the whole app, it needs to be an abstract class for ease of use. How would I go about creating a generic function that gets title and content and displays a generic dialog?

The usage of the MatDialog usually includes it's initialization on the component's contructor, but seeing as this class is abstract, I wouldn't call the constructor anywhere. I've tried wrapping the call of the alert component on a public function, but the non-initialization of the MatDialog service is blocking it from showing.

Alert component:

```
export class AlertDialogComponent implements OnInit {

    modalTitle: string;
    modalContent: string;

    constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {
        this.modalTitle = data.title;
        this.modalContent = data.content;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

}
```

Utilitary Class:

```
import { AlertDialogComponent } from '../../app/genericComponentes/alert-dialog/alert-dialog.component';
import { MatDialogConfig, MatDialog } from "@angular/material";

.
.
.

export abstract class Utils {

    public static fireMaterialAlert(content, title = 'Atenção') {
        const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();

        dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
        dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;

        dialogConfig.data = {
            id: 1,
            title: title,
            content: content,
        };

        this.dialog.open(AlertDialogComponent, dialogConfig);
    }
}
```

Creating a constructor has no effects. Instancianting `this.dialog = new MatDialog()` fires errors in the IDE, saying that I need 7 different parameters. Ignoring that error, during runtime I get `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'position' of undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

I know it would be late to this answer but I was around exactly same problem and what I found out is that you need to create a special method that is responsible to open dialog in your abstract class:

```
public constructDialog<T>(TCtor: new (...args: any[]) => T,data: any): MatDialogRef<T,any> {
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(TCtor, dialogConfig);
    return dialogRef;
 }
```

Then you may call it this way:

```
const dialogRef = this.constructDialog(ConfirmationDialog,{
           data:{
        message: 'Are you sure want to delete?',
        buttonText: {
          ok: 'Save',
          cancel: 'No'
        }
      }
   });
```

ConfirmationDialog would be any component.

Here is the working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-generic-creation

Comment: your solution still has `MatDialog` injected in the constructor which topic starter wanted to escape

Comment: This doesn't accomplish anything.  You're just adding a wrapper class to MatDialog, which is pointless